# Removing Null values from an Array Collection using Flex

Tags: null, arraycollection

I have an ArrayCollection that I want to have all null or empty values removed.

What line in the code might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the faster way in terms of performance:

```
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public function cleanArrayCollection(collection:ArrayCollection):ArrayCollection{
        var currentArray:Array = null;    
        var newCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        for(var i:int = 0; i < collection.length; i++){
            currentArray = collection.getItemAt(i);
            if(currentArray != null && currentArray.length != 0){
                newCollection.addItem(currentArray);
            }
        }

        return newCollection;
    }
]]></mx:Script>
```

Edit: Removed critical bugs in logic.